# Can flexbox divide items evenly on multiple rows?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've played around with responsive flexbox grids, with no media queries.

http://jsbin.com/qurumisu/1 (rescale the window to see how it works)

It fits as many flex items as it can per row and stretches their width equally to fill the whole line. However, this doesn't help "orphan" items. If the first line fits 5/6 items there is only one left for the second line, making it stretch much wider than it's siblings. I would prefer to avoid this behavior by having the elements divided evenly on the amount of rows required.

Is this possible?

Comment: Flexbox is not a grid system, at least not the way grid systems are thought of in CSS.

Comment: @cinnamon: I know. However there's a lot of things in css which aren't meant to be used as they currently are. CSS sprites for example. And that still solves a big problem :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, not without media queries adjusting the flex-basis value.  Flex items that stretch and wrap attempt to maximize the amount of items that fit on each row.

You may want to consider using the multi-column module instead, which will attempt to equally distribute elements across all of the columns created:

```
.foo {
    columns: 100px;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: I can't use multi-columns for this purpose, but thanks :)

There's a new css-feature coming specifically for grids, which might help me solve this, although I think not.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for exactly the same thing (lining up image thumbnails in a flex-wrap thing). Your sample gave me some directions and I played with it ab bit and came up with the following:

Well, if you'd be willing to add some extra markup to the HTML code, it is indeed possible. Assuming, that I can show `n` items on full width screen, I added `n-1` items of `<div class="hidden-item">` at the end of the container and modified the CSS code so that these hidden items have the same *width* but no *height*. This way, they wrap around as well, forcing the last item(s) to shrink, without increasing the height of the container.

Result is here:
 http://output.jsbin.com/qaxatujaho/1

Comment: While this requires a lot of boilerplate code and isn't really what I was looking for, it does provide a practical and previously undocumented alternative I hadn't thought of. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is super old, but I was searching for a couple hours for a solution to this issue. Your solution works absolutely perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript solution I wrote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991883/how-to-make-every-row-in-a-grid-list-have-the-same-number-of-items-using-flexbo):

```
var resize = function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#container');
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  var css = document.querySelector('#js-css');

  var itemWidth = 100;
  var containerWidth = $(container).width();

  var perRowCount = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);
  var rowCount = Math.ceil(items.length / perRowCount);
  var newPerRowCount = Math.floor(items.length / rowCount);

  var newItemWidth = (containerWidth / newPerRowCount) - (parseInt($(items[0]).css('margin')) * 2);

  css.innerHTML = '.item { width: ' + newItemWidth + 'px; }';
};
```

You can run the `resize()` function when the viewport is resized.

Here is an example: (or alternatively a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yimesa))

```js
var resize = function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#container');
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  var css = document.querySelector('#js-css');

  var itemWidth = 100;
  var containerWidth = $(container).width();

  var perRowCount = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);
  var rowCount = Math.ceil(items.length / perRowCount);
  var newPerRowCount = Math.floor(items.length / rowCount);

  var newItemWidth = (containerWidth / newPerRowCount) - (parseInt($(items[0]).css('margin')) * 2);

  css.innerHTML = '.item { width: ' + newItemWidth + 'px; }';
};

var increase = function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#container');

  $(container).width($(container).width() + 15);

  resize();
};

var decrease = function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#container');

  $(container).width($(container).width() - 15);

  resize();
};

resize();
```

```css
#container {
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #8BC34A;
  align-self: center;
  -ms-align-self: center;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
}
.item {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flex;
}
span {
  align-self: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-align-self: center;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#title {
  display: flex;
  color: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#sub-title {
  display: flex;
  color: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style id="js-css">
  </style>

  <span id="title">Flexbox Grid</span>
  <span id="sub-title">How to make each row have the same number of items?</span>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>ITEM #6</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onClick="increase()">+</button>
  <button onClick="resize()">Resize Items</button>
  <button onClick="decrease()">-</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I advice to use media queries, like [twitter bootstraps adaptive grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) instead of custom javascript for layouts.

Comment: Note that this also injects the CSS in the DOM rather than using [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) directly through JS. Also, it **depends on jQuery** so you can't use this solution unless you're already using that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but opted for a different solution than the one you asked for. Instead of trying to distribute the amount of items evenly along all rows and columns, I set a max-width property on them so that they don't assume the entire row's space.

Comment: Obviously I know about max-width. All css grid frameworks used max-width when I asked this, and I was trying to get away from that, because it's not very flexible and require a ton of breakpoints.